# How to create bootable Backup (ubuntu) From Virtual box

Tags: 16.04, backup

I have installed Ubuntu 16.. on virtual box.
I need to backup this Ubuntu to sd card or USB and i will install this on physical machine. How can i do that?

Comment: I am afraid that there are some special drivers for the VirtualBox emulation of hardware, that might not work well with real hardware. I think it would be easier to make a fresh installation in a physical machine. You can probably keep `/home` with your personal files and tweaks. I think you must be prepared to reinstall the program packages that you have added to your system in VirtualBox. - But if you intend to run VirtualBox in another computer, it should be enough to copy the corresponding virtual disk, vdi-file, to that new computer, and let VirtualBox use it there.

Comment: actualy my problem is i dont have internet my physical machine.
I need to install dnsmasq and nfs server. I installed them in the virtual box (ubuntu) just i want to move there

Comment: Can you connect the internal drive of the 'target machine' to the computer, where VirtualBox is running? Or can you get a USB pendrive (for example with 16 GB) and install Ubuntu into it and after that move it to the target computer and check if it boots?

Comment: i can connect usb into machine, bu i dont know how to import my machine as iso file.

Comment: You can install Ubuntu into the USB drive in a machine with internet. After that you can move the USB drive and it will probably boot in that computer. If you avoid installing proprietary drivers, installed Ubuntu systems are portable between computers. See this link for more details, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389

Answer (score 3):

The steps below describes how to create the bootable backup ISO of your VM.  You'll have the ISO.  If just having the backup is all needed. You can disregard the references to transferring the ISO image to a new drive.

The target drive has to be as least the size of the source drive.  The size doesn't matter as long as it's not smaller.  If it's smaller the transfer will fail.

These are the steps needed:

- Create ISO image from VirtualMachine's HD
- Copy the ISO to the physical Drive
- Fix the integrity of the physical drive or partition

**Creating the ISO image from the VM's HD**

```
$ VBoxManage clonehd ["source vdi pathname"] ["target iso pathname"] --format RAW
```

The pathnames will be replaced with something similar to:

```
Source VDI:    "~/VirtualBox VMs/Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
Target ISO:    "~/isoimages/ubuntu-16.04lts.iso"
```

The quotes are only needed if you have spaces in the pathname.  Don't include the brackets.

Now place that ISO image to the new target drive (using the example source and destination above):

```
$ sudo dd if="~/isoimages/ubuntu-16.04lts.iso" of=[/dev/sdc] bs=4M status=progress
```

In the command above the `/dev/sdc` is new target drive that you are transferring the VM drive to.  Don't include the brackets in the command.

**Very Important!**  The **dd** command is a lowlevel command that will not perform normal safeguards.  If you make a mistake and run it on an unintended drive, it'll be overwritten.  You lose the current data on the drive.  So be very careful with the `of=` command.

Now run **Gparted** on the new target drive.  Use this to resize the partitions to accommodate for the difference in drive size.

*I perform these steps often in having a default installation for fresh Ubuntu Installs for clients machines.*

Answer (score -1):

Try making an archive:

`sudo tar -cpzf name.tar.gz /`

Then start a live session and make a bootable ext4 partition, mount it, and:

`sudo tar -xpzf name.tar.gz -C /target_drive`

Then change the `/etc/fstab` to the correct `UUIDs` then `chroot` into that system, and run a `sudo update-grub`, then come back and tell me if it works or not cause I didn't tried...

don't delete the system from the virtual box, just in case it doesn't work...